# is action hook not working on quick edit?

Tags: terms

This code is not working on quick edit?

```
function cpt ($term_id) {
  print_r($_POST);
}
add_action('create_post_tag', 'cpt');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [WPSeek's page on the `create_{$taxonomy}` action hook](http://wpseek.com/hook/create_taxonomy/), and also the new-to-me [WordPress Developers' docs on the same hook](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/), there are two required parameters:

> #### Parameters
>
> `$term_id` (int) (Required) Term ID.
>   `$tt_id` (int) (Required) Term taxonomy ID.

So your function is missing the `$tt_id` parameter.